# Delimit Std-Out and Std-Err dumps when redirecting to same file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can this: `command > file.txt 2>&1` be altered in such a way to have it prepend some "header" (and possibly append some "tail") text to each stream?

For example, "file.txt" would read:

[std_output]Hello world![/std_output]

[std_error]Crash![/std_error]

EDIT: The caveat is that this operation should only involve writing to a SINGLE file (i.e. no other temp files should be involved). The writing would be preferred to be atomic, though multiple writes via multiple commands that can be compounded into one single command is also acceptable.

Comment: Can you process it separately? (i.e. add the head&tail later)

Comment: Note that `command > file.txt 2>&1` may interleave stdout and stderr.

Comment: [Possible solution (involve some temp files)](https://tio.run/##PY4/D4IwFMT3fooHDkBATFwhXdTEzQRxc8FSpEltTf/EwfjZawvK9O4uv3u5W6dH5ygZJSQrJgi3Pa216ZksR4yYMPDomEiz9/C0RqfxTvlCdBVx4SGqVFbN@ZFyLgt4ScX7KM6qT4IHxmlJ0D3PYZawlpNC5SYcwNIa2GL/BU0Dzu3@dGkBzxDpDAQA//wfOTTNkgXG1xc/BUE59wU).

Comment: @GerhardBarnard That is not the issue here. `command > file.txt 2>&1` works just fine in regards to obtaining both out and error without one overwriting the other. The issue is separating/delimiting them in such a way to be able to parse them later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
>file.txt echo [std_output]
>tempfile.txt echo [std_error]
command >>file.txt 2>>tempfile.txt
>>file.txt echo [/std_output]
>>tempfile.txt echo [/std_error]
type tempfile.txt >>file.txt
del tempfile.txt
```

Is possibly a solution. It's so simple I'll not bother to explain it.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it clear in the original question, but I thought it was obvious that I'm trying to avoid multiple temp files. I need this - if possible - to be one single atomic command involving one single output file.

Comment: also this "sorts" for STDOUT and STDERR. The messages may come in any order (and as I understand the question the order should be maintained).